# ebay api, rover links not working

Tags: android, ebay-api, mobile-browser

so I have the following link at my website:

```
http://rover.ebay.com/rover/1/711-53200-19255-0/1?icep_ff3=2&amp;pub=0000000000&amp;toolid=10001&amp;campid=000000000&amp;customid=&amp;icep_item=120539950457&amp;ipn=psmain&amp;icep_vectorid=229466&amp;kwid=902099&amp;mtid=824&amp;kw=lg
```

The link works perfectly fine in all browsers, but mobile browser. When I follow the link from my cell phone (with Chrome browser), it attempts to load page, but then the browser window closes and returns to previous page.

I tried to compare my links with ebay link generator tool and they look the same.

What might be the problem here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please add what os your phone uses and if you have an eBay app installed.

Comment: It's Android 5.1.1 and I have no eBay app installed

Comment: I'm also getting the similar issue. Whenever I try to open the link in webview it doesn't open and when I try to open in chrome browser it automatically closes the tab. Here's the video for reference.  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaqLJJhV8ZY&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: I'm also having this problem when testing my app on an emulator.  Pixel3a API 29 emulator.  No ebay app installed, so I would expect the rover link to open the correct eBay url in Chrome (or default) browser.